# PNG file not showing checkerboard in Windows Photo Viewer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, png

I saved my PNG file in Photoshop with png-24 and transparency checked. But when I open this image in Windows Photo Viewer, the checkerboard is gone. Is there something wrong about Windows Photo Viewer or my saving technique?

Comment: If I remember correctly, it always shows a white bg (kinda like any pdf viewer by default). You could open up the image in your web browser or perhaps get a third party application specifically for viewing images. I can't recommend any.

Comment: Windows photo viewer doesn't use a chequered background to show transparency.

Answer (score 3):

The checkerboard is a Photoshop feature which highlights transparency. Your PNG is probably ok, but the checkerboard is not visible via the 'Windows Photo Viewer', which renders transparency as plain white.